# mongodb $lookup single field in array subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

say I have a collection of blog "posts", and each post might have a `related` field, which is an array of related blog posts objects, something like this:

```
db.posts.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "name" : "post 1"  },
   { "_id" : 2, "name" : "post 2"  },
   { "_id" : 3, "name" : "post with related", related: [{tagline: 'read post1', post: 1}, {tagline: 'more in post2', post: 2}]  }
])
```

Now I want to fetch posts and "expand" the "related.post" field with `$lookup` AND keep the `tagline` field,
I tried something like this but no luck...

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'posts',
        localField: 'related.post',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'related.post'
    }}
])
```

Is there a (simple) way to achieve that?
Thx!

Comment: why not use mongoose.populate({path: 'related.post', model: 'Post', select: {}})

Comment: You assume I am using mongoose.... well I do and that's what I am indeed doing, but I want to know if it is possible to do so with "vanilla" mongo, saving the extra round-trips of "populate"

Comment: one other way might be to mimic mongoose "populate", like you need to `{$lookup: {..., as: 'populatedPost'}}` and then use some kind of "$project" or "$addFeilds" aggregation or simply pass the response of the query through some response maker function.

ps: you should use another alias not "related.post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this strategy will work

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'posts',
        localField: 'related.post',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'posts'
    }},
    {$unwind: {
        path: '$related',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        'related.post': {
            $filter: {
                input: '$posts',
                as: 'posts',
                cond: { $eq: ['$related.post', '$$posts._id'] }
            }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
        'related.post': {$arrayElemAt: ['$related.post', 0]}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: { $first: '$name' },
        related: { '$push': '$related' }
    }},
])
```

Comment: This works: update and I'll mark as solved
db.posts.aggregate([
{$lookup: {
 from: 'posts',
 localField: 'related.post',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'posts'
}},
{$unwind: {
 path: '$related',
 preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}},
{$addFields: {
 'related.post': {
  $filter: {
   input: '$posts',
   as: 'posts',
   cond: { $eq: ['$related.post', '$$posts._id'] }
  }
 }
}},
{$addFields: {
 'related.post': {$arrayElemAt: ['$related.post', 0]}
}},
{$group: {
 _id: '$_id',
 name: { $first: '$name' },
 related: { '$push': '$related' }
}},
])